# Как сделать прокрутку блока по горизонтали зажатой клавишей мыши?

Tags: css, jquery

Есть блок, у которого скрыта горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.
Как можно сделать прокрутку зажатым курсором мыши влева/вправо, как на мобильном?

Пример на эмуляции мобильного:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="managers" class="managers_wrapper">
    <div class="managers_list">Контент</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.managers_wrapper {
    width: 550px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.managers_wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.managers_wrapper {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
.managers_list {
    width: 838px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Слишком мало вводных данных для конкретной помощи, но с учётом того, что в теги к вопросу втёрся jQuery, то могу порекомендовать плагин [TouchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin).

По ссылке найдёте и демо-сайт.